# selenium test regarding css selector which does not contain class or id attribute

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to fetch element from html

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; cursor: url(&quot;&quot;), default;" class="yfiles-canvascontrol" tabindex="1"><div style="bottom: 0px; right: 0px;" class="yfiles-svgpanel"><div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;"><svg style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;pointer-events:none"><g transform="translate(348.5, 128.5)" style="pointer-events:visiblePainted"><g transform="translate(75 175)" class="aw-relations-groupNodeSvg aw-relations-detailLevel0">
        <rect stroke="rgb(191,161,229)" class="aw-widgets-cellListItemNode" height="125" width="300" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
        <rect stroke="rgb(191,161,229)" class="aw-relations-noeditable-area" height="125" width="300" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
        <rect stroke="rgb(191,161,229)" class="aw-relations-noeditable-area" height="125" width="300" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
        <rect stroke="rgb(191,161,229)" height="125" width="300" class="aw-relations-seedNodeSvg" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
        <rect height="125" width="300" class="aw-relations-noeditable-area" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>

        <g>
            <rect fill="rgb(191,161,229)" height="" width="10" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
            <line stroke="rgb(191,161,229)" y2="" x2="300" y1="" x1="0"></line>
            <g transform="translate(65)">
                <g id="header">
                    <g class="" transform="translate(0 20)">
                        <rect fill="none" height="28px" width="230px" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
                        <text transform="translate(0 21)" ontouchstart="onEditLabelClicked(this)" onclick="onEditLabelClicked(this)" onmouseout="onEditLabelMouseOut(this)" onmouseover="onEditLabelMouseOver(this)" data-id="SR::N::Ase0LogicalElement..Fnd0LogicalBOMLine..5.6ZarDeTC8VoL5B.J$vlO1AI8VI9qC.Group:/Thid_wCYVM0YsoaNeFC,,AWBCB" data-width="100%-80" data-property-name="awb0ArchetypeRevName" class="aw-widgets-cellListCellTitle" id="title">block1</text>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(0 46)" data-translate-top="title">
                        <text transform="translate(0 13)" ontouchstart="onEditLabelClicked(this)" onclick="onEditLabelClicked(this)" onmouseout="onEditLabelMouseOut(this)" onmouseover="onEditLabelMouseOver(this)" data-id="SR::N::Ase0LogicalElement..Fnd0LogicalBOMLine..5.6ZarDeTC8VoL5B.J$vlO1AI8VI9qC.Group:/Thid_wCYVM0YsoaNeFC,,AWBCB" data-width="100%-80" data-property-name="ID" class="aw-widgets-cellListCellItemType" id="subTitle">000444</text>
                    </g>
                    <g transform="translate(0 63)" data-translate-top="subTitle">
                        <text class="aw-widgets-cellListCellPropertyValue" transform="translate(0 15)">Revision: A</text>

                    </g>
                </g>

                <g transform="translate(0 93)" data-translate-top="subTitle" data-translate-y="30">
                    <g ontouchstart="runCommand(this)" onclick="runCommand(this)" data-commandid="com.siemens.splm.client.relations.internal.commands.expandincoming" data-contextmenu="" data-tooltip="Show Incoming Relations" data-id="SR::N::Ase0LogicalElement..Fnd0LogicalBOMLine..5.6ZarDeTC8VoL5B.J$vlO1AI8VI9qC.Group:/Thid_wCYVM0YsoaNeFC,,AWBCB" class="hidden" transform="translate(0 0)">
                        <rect class="hidden" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
                        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAApklEQVR42mNgGCxg6tSpBkCcQHWDJ0+e7DBlypT/QLqBJgZD8XxaGQzC+/v7+wVoYTAIn58+fboCMRG0HotmQvg9KGLxGgzyHhkGgw0H+iiAFgaDMc5gocRgvGmcTINBweBAThjPh6aIArIiDpfBsJyGJbmdJzodE2swKFmSlDmINHg+MbmpARkDNd0nYHABsS4kGOtklWajBqOnApwYlKyIKhbpAQDnZhqtR8K2hAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></image>
                        <text class="hidden" transform="translate(22 15)">0</text>
                    </g>
                    <g ontouchstart="runCommand(this)" onclick="runCommand(this)" data-commandid="com.siemens.splm.client.relations.internal.commands.expanddown" data-contextmenu="" data-tooltip="" data-id="SR::N::Ase0LogicalElement..Fnd0LogicalBOMLine..5.6ZarDeTC8VoL5B.J$vlO1AI8VI9qC.Group:/Thid_wCYVM0YsoaNeFC,,AWBCB" class="hidden" transform="translate(55 0)">
                        <rect class="hidden" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
                        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAAq0lEQVR42mNgoCWYMmXKfnx46tSp66dPn65AjsH/CeHJkyc3jBpMvsEgTcgYaNB9XAYDaQeyLEFKJTgNhorNp5XBILy/v79fgBYGg/B5og3HZjDI61BDC7DIvQdmIgNyDSaE3wMtDqCFwWAMdHkCTQwGYZzlCgUGg4LDAaeLQaUZOYYSFYF4cqkDFkPPk5SeiTR4P8WGYjF4PtVqGySDC6hajYEiCG9apTUAABIoGpLjU/7fAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></image>
                        <text class="hidden" transform="translate(22 15)">0</text>
                    </g>
                    <g ontouchstart="runCommand(this)" onclick="runCommand(this)" data-commandid="com.siemens.splm.client.relations.internal.commands.expandtoparent" data-contextmenu="" data-tooltip="Show Parent" data-id="SR::N::Ase0LogicalElement..Fnd0LogicalBOMLine..5.6ZarDeTC8VoL5B.J$vlO1AI8VI9qC.Group:/Thid_wCYVM0YsoaNeFC,,AWBCB" class="aw-relations-nodeExpandToParentTargetSvg" transform="translate(135 0)">
                        <rect class="hidden" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
                        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAArklEQVR42mNgGJFg8uTJDVOnTk2gpoEOU6ZMuQ/E/0GGU2zg9OnTFYCG7QcZCMMUGdzf3y8ANKQf2UCKDQaFIdCA99gMJctgaDiex2UgyQaDwhHoyvWEDCTaYFA4ghTh8zbJBkPD8T4pBhI0GCgRQI6BxLrYAD19Ui2MkVx/n+oGI5cBxEYiyekYmn3nU91gtIyyn+oGE8raVCndkDIRdQ3Glu2pajBy+FO1BsEHAGDp1Mi22dsnAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></image>
                        <text class="hidden" transform="translate(22 15)">1</text>
                    </g>
                    <g ontouchstart="runCommand(this)" onclick="runCommand(this)" data-commandid="com.siemens.splm.client.relations.internal.commands.children" data-contextmenu="" data-tooltip="" data-id="SR::N::Ase0LogicalElement..Fnd0LogicalBOMLine..5.6ZarDeTC8VoL5B.J$vlO1AI8VI9qC.Group:/Thid_wCYVM0YsoaNeFC,,AWBCB" class="hidden" transform="translate(172 0)">
                        <rect class="hidden" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></rect>
                        <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAAmUlEQVR42mNgGNJg6tSp64HYgOoGT5ky5T8U9wOBAC0MBuH3QFxAC4Nh+P7kyZMdaGEwGIPCf/r06QpUNxiGga5vIDn8iTEYFv5AHyTQwmAY3k9U+JNhMAzPxxv+FBgMwuepbTDh9E5OEBCVQkiJNJLKFCIMBOXCAGpmkPdkZQwCBs8nOyvjMPg8xYUPmsGkZVdiAEXhSC8AAEMZxPHTyECZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" height="22px" width="22px" transform="translate(0 0)"></image>
                        <text class="hidden" transform="translate(22 15)">0</text>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <image preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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" id="JTThumbnail" height="46px" width="46px" transform="translate(17 19)"></image>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(214 164)"><rect stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="aw-widgets-cellListItemSelected" y="0" x="0" height="22" width="22" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"></rect>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(236 141)"><text transform="translate(0 0)" dy="1em" fill-opacity="1" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" text-anchor="start" font-weight="600" font-style="normal" font-size="16px" font-family="Segoe UI">P</text></g>
    </g>
    <defs>
    </defs>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="yfiles-overlaypanel">
    <div class="yfiles-canvascontrol" tabindex="1" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 125px; display: none;">
    <div class="yfiles-svgpanel">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;">
    <svg style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;pointer-events:none">
    <g transform="translate(0 0)" style="pointer-events:visiblePainted">
    <rect fill-opacity="1" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" y="0" x="0" height="125" width="300" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"></rect>
    </g>
    <defs>
    </defs>
    </svg>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="cursor: default; display: none;" class="yfiles-scrollbar yfiles-scrollbar-vertical" tabindex="1">
    <div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-up">▲</div>
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range yfiles-scrollbar-range-vertical" tabindex="1">
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range-content"><div class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider">
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider-content">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-down">▼</div>
    </div>
    <div style="cursor: default; display: none;" class="yfiles-scrollbar yfiles-scrollbar-horizontal" tabindex="1">
    <div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-left">◄</div>
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range yfiles-scrollbar-range-horizontal" tabindex="1">
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range-content"><div class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider">
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider-content"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-right">►</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style="cursor: default; width: 0px; bottom: 0px;" class="yfiles-scrollbar yfiles-scrollbar-vertical" tabindex="1">
    <div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-up">▲</div>
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range yfiles-scrollbar-range-vertical" tabindex="1">
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range-content">
    <div style="height: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider">
    <div class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider-content"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-down">▼</div>
    </div>
    <div style="cursor: default; height: 0px; right: 0px; display: none;" class="yfiles-scrollbar yfiles-scrollbar-horizontal" tabindex="1"><
div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-left">◄</div><div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range yfiles-scrollbar-range-horizontal" tabindex="1">
<div class="yfiles-scrollbar-range-content">
<div style="width: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider">
<div class="yfiles-scrollbar-slider-content"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="yfiles-button yfiles-button-right">►</div>
</div>
</div>
```

file which is of type `ISingleLocator`.
Code is given as below:

```
<rect stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="1" fill-opacity="1" class="aw-widgets-cellListItemSelected" y="0" x="0" height="22" width="22" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"></rect> from given code.
```

I tried with this:

```
ISingleLocator m_nodeContainer1 = $( "div.aw-relations-innerContainer div div div svg g g rect.aw-widgets-cellListItemSelected " );
```

but I am unable to get that location.Please tell me exact CSS selector to fetch that `rect` tag.

Comment: This doesn't look like Selenium to me. What is `ISingleLocator`? Your question is the only place in the entire web that references such an interface, and I don't think Selenium uses `$()` syntax though I could be wrong on that count.

Comment: Actually  ISingleLocator is locator to find single element.Is there any solution through which i can fetch that rect tag?

Comment: @BoltClock forget about this ISingleLocator suppose i want this rect tag as in WebElement then what is the solution for it.

Comment: what language are you using? These doesn't seem to be Java at least because there you can find elements by using find.by(...) syntax

Comment: I am writing it in java.Lets forget about that ISinglLocator if i want that rect tag in selenium how can i get that tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to find a `WebElement` with Selenium and Java. 
These could be:

**With CSS selector:**

```
WebElement rect = find(By.cssSelector("aw-widgets-cellListItemSelected"));
```

**With XPATH selector:**

```
WebElement rect = find(By.xpath("//rect [contains(@class, 'aw-widgets-cellListItemSelected')]));
```

**With ID selector:**

```
WebElement rect = find(By.id("<your ID here>"));
```

But forget the ID one because you don't have an @ID for the given rect.

If you have more then one `rect` with this classname you can also use `WebElements` instead of `WebElement` so you will get a list with all results.

Comment: I am having one more doubt before creating that rect tag its appear on web browser but its not get loaded and before loading that tag selenium test end so that rect tag is unable to locate on that page so my question is is there any method in selenium  which keep that page in loading state until and unless that rect tag is not fully appear or saved.

Comment: You could wait for the element to be loaded e.g. wait for max. 30 sec: `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(this.getDriver(), 30);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("aw-widgets-cellListItemSelected")));`

Comment: hey suppose if rect tag does not contain id and class attribute then how to write wait.until(By) method using stroke and fill.

Comment: same as with a normal class and xpath.. so e.g. `find(By.xpath("//rect [contains(@stroke, 'rgb(0,0,0)')]))` .. you can use any attribute as you like

Comment: hey i did all these step but still i am facing problem actually using selector that rectangle appear on webpage and also perform click operation using  org.openqa.selenium.interactions Action class but still its not able to click that rectangle when cursor goes on that location i.e only rectangle visible but not able to click on that rectangle.

Comment: you could try `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(<your find by statement>)`  .. this waits until an element ist clickable .. if it also doesn't work you could try `Thread.sleep(<time in ms>)` to sleep until you think your element becomes clickable

Comment: And after click event if i want to wait until that rectangle get saved in server side then which method to use?

Comment: Hey i am having this tag:                                                                         <svg stroke-dasharray="" vector-effect="" width="22" height="22" visibility="visible" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" stroke="rgba(255,215,0,1)"><use xlink:href="#75"></use></svg>               i want to perform right click operation on it to select appropriate option from list how to select it?

Comment: See here e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856324/Perform-right-click-action-using-WebDriver ... you can find a lot of information by using google. If you having problem because some of your efforts fail then please open a new question instead of writing a comment here so others can help you too :)